# Como fazer um RSS feed funcionar no Angular 4?

Tags: angular

O código abaixo está funcionando numa página **HTML**

```html
  

  <html>
        <head>
            <title>Titulo da página</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                rssfeed_url = new Array(); 
                rssfeed_url[0]="http://esporte.uol.com.br/ultimas/index.xml";  
                rssfeed_frame_width="300"; 
                rssfeed_frame_height="260"; 
                rssfeed_scroll="on"; 
                rssfeed_scroll_step="6"; 
                rssfeed_scroll_bar="off"; 
                rssfeed_target="_blank"; 
                rssfeed_font_size="12"; 
                rssfeed_font_face=""; 
                rssfeed_border="on"; 
                rssfeed_css_url=""; 
                rssfeed_title="on"; 
                rssfeed_title_name=""; 
                rssfeed_title_bgcolor="#3366ff"; 
                rssfeed_title_color="#fff"; 
                rssfeed_title_bgimage=""; 
                rssfeed_footer="off"; 
                rssfeed_footer_name="rss feed"; 
                rssfeed_footer_bgcolor="#fff"; 
                rssfeed_footer_color="#333"; 
                rssfeed_footer_bgimage=""; 
                rssfeed_item_title_length="50"; 
                rssfeed_item_title_color="#666"; 
                rssfeed_item_bgcolor="#fff"; 
                rssfeed_item_bgimage=""; 
                rssfeed_item_border_bottom="on"; 
                rssfeed_item_source_icon="off"; 
                rssfeed_item_date="off"; 
                rssfeed_item_description="on"; 
                rssfeed_item_description_length="120"; 
                rssfeed_item_description_color="#666"; 
                rssfeed_item_description_link_color="#333"; 
                rssfeed_item_description_tag="off"; 
                rssfeed_no_items="0"; 
                rssfeed_cache = "e90320463f8111afd3b519c711ff89e3"; 
            </script> 

            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://feed.surfing-waves.com/js/rss-feed.js"></script> 

        </head>

        <body>
            <div style="text-align:right; width:300px;">powered by <a href="http://www.surfing-waves.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank" style="color:#ccc;font-size:10px">Surfing Waves</a></div> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

Como poderia fazer ele funcionar num projeto angular 4 ?

Comment: Qual é a dificuldade? Já fez algum projecto em angular?

Comment: sim, eu já fiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode baixar o documento usando `HttpClient` e pode usar o:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Exemplo básico:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

...

title = '';
description = '';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

...

downloadXml() {
    this.http.get("http://site.com/feed.rss").subscribe(res => {
         parseXml(res); //Baixo o XML
    }, err => {
         console.log(err);
    });
}

...

parseXml(data) {
    let parser = new DOMParser;
    let doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");

    this.title = doc.querySelector("channel > title").text;
    this.description = doc.querySelector("channel > description").text;

    ...
}
```

E no HTML ficaria algo como:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>{{description}}</h2>
```

Para pegar os itens terá que ir iterando com `for` e pegando somente os textos, por exemplo:

```
title = '';
description = '';
items = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

...

parseXml(data) {
    let parser = new DOMParser;
    let doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");

    this.title = doc.querySelector("channel > title").text;
    this.description = doc.querySelector("channel > description").text;

    let items = doc.querySelectorAll("channel > item");
    let objs = [];

    for (let el of items) {
         let obj = {
             "link": el.querySelector("link"),
             "title": el.querySelector("title"),
             "description": el.querySelector("description")
         };

         objs.push(obj);
    }

    this.items = objs;
}
```

E no HTML ficaria assim (usando `*ngIf` para verificar se existe algo e `*ngFor` para iterar os valores em `this.items`):

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>{{description}}</h2>

<div *ngIf="items.length">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        <h3><a href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a></h3>
        <p>{{item.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: eu entendi que você colocou a classe de serviços e a página HTML, mas o a classe de componente como vai ficar?

Comment: @wladyband como assim, você quer que um serviço em background fique atualizando sozinho os dados? Esse exemplo que postei é o básico de como fazer o "parse" do RSS (que até então me parecia a sua dificuldade). Exatamente aonde é a sua dificuldade agora?

Comment: me desculpe, só tinha um pouco de paciência comigo, eu consigo compreender seu código, os códigos então sem dizer onde é componente ou é serviço, eu conseguir identificar onde se encontra as páginas.
Esrou me referindo a isso:
class MidiaExibirComponent
class MidiaService

Comment: @wladyband você já desenvolvel algo em Angular? É pra web ou pra mobile (ionic)? Porque é assim, Angular você usa de "maneira" livre, cria a classe, cria o template, no caso o HTML ali pode ir dentro de um documento foo.html e carregar assim no seu `.ts` `templateUrl: "foo.html"`, se quiser injetar o HTML dentro do .ts usaria assim https://pastebin.com/4NASVzvS

Comment: entendi, vou pegar seu código e realizar os testes, muito obrigado

Comment: @wladyband mas é um projeto WEB ou é um aplicativo hibrido (ionic por exemplo) para celular?

Comment: é um projeto web em angular 4

Comment: @wladyband e como estruturou a primeira página? Chegou a criar alguma página a mais, tipo uma "página 2" ou "página de contato"? ps: só pra constar  `...` no código que postei acima é de exemplo, é pra dizer que ali iria mais códigos, mas a ideia é que se conhece o básico do Angular vai entender aonde é o construtt e aonde vão os métodos ;)

Comment: você respondeu certo minha pergunta, foi eu que fiz a pergunta mau feita, mesmo assim muito obrigado, vou ver se faço uma nova postagem e dessa vez criando uma pergunta mais completa.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento como pegar a "img" do **content:encoded**, que é onde tem o src da img?

Comment: @BraianSilva tá respondido https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/395784/3635, em futuros comentários de preferencia já coloque o link de suas perguntas, se já existirem ;)