# Como pegar o src de uma img do <content:encoded> Angular 7

Tags: angular, xml

Estou fazendo um Rss Feed e quero pegar uma imagem do `<content:encoded>` e usar como thumbnail, como resolver?

Estou usando esse feed como exemplo: http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/feed

```
parseXml(data: any){
  let parser = new DOMParser();
  let doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');

  let objs = [];

  this.xml2 = doc.getElementsByTagName('feed')[0] || doc.getElementsByTagName('rss')[0] || [];

  /*  RSS */
  if (this.xml2.tagName === 'rss') {

    let items = doc.querySelectorAll("channel > item");
    for (let el of items as any) {
      let obj = {
        "title": el.querySelector("title").textContent,
        "link": el.querySelector("link").textContent,
        "author": el.querySelector("creator").textContent,
        "description": el.querySelector("description").textContent,
        "pubDate": el.querySelector("pubDate").textContent,
        "content": el.querySelector("encoded").textContent,
        "thumbnail": el.getElementsByTagName('img').item(1).getAttribute('src')
        /* Erro ao tentar pegar a img */
      }
      objs.unshift(obj);
    }
    this.items = objs;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A imagem esta em um CDATA, logo ele é como texto para o DOMParser e não como HTML, então não vai encontrar nada, por isso `.getElementsByTagName('img')` retorna um NodeList vazio

Outra coisa, tags com namespace como `<content:encoded>` precisam usar uma função para tal, se `getElementsByTagName` pega elementos normais então para elementos com namespace deve-se usar `getElementsByTagNameNS`.

Olhando no seu FEED o namespace de `:content` é `http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/`, então um exemplo para pegar o conteudo seria:

```
var ces = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/', 'encoded');

console.log(ces.length);
```

Veja um teste, vai retornar 1 se encontrar ao menos uma tag:

```js
var data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    >

<channel>
    <title>Parceria Social de Empregos</title>
    <atom:link href="http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br</link>
    <description>Um blog com vagas de emprego</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Sat, 06 Jul 2019 17:05:44 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <language>pt-BR</language>
    <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
    <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=4.9.10</generator>

    <image>
        <url>http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/cropped-logo_01-1-32x32.png</url>
        <title>Parceria Social de Empregos</title>
        <link>http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br</link>
        <width>32</width>
        <height>32</height>
    </image> 
    <item>
        <title>Estágio loja de autopeças Av Ipanema</title>
        <link>http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/06/07/2019/estagio-loja-de-autopecas-av-ipanema-3/</link>
        <comments>http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/06/07/2019/estagio-loja-de-autopecas-av-ipanema-3/#respond</comments>
        <pubDate>Sat, 06 Jul 2019 17:05:44 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[Watanabe]]></dc:creator>
        <category><![CDATA[Vaga de Emprego]]></category>

        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/?p=25590</guid>
        <description><![CDATA[Você gosta do mundo automotivo? Esta pode ser sua chance de conhecer mais sobre a área! Obrigatório: &#8211; Estar cursando o 2º ou 3º ano do Ensino Médio em 2019; &#8211; Residir próximo a Avenida Ipanema; &#8211; Gostar do mundo automotivo; &#8211; Aptidão em português e matemática; &#8211; Disponibilidade aos domingos. Enviar currículo para rh@watanabeautopecas.com.br]]></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p><img class="alignnone wp-image-1941" src="http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/estagio-watanabe-300x75.jpg" alt="" width="420" height="105" srcset="http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/estagio-watanabe-300x75.jpg 300w, http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/estagio-watanabe.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 420px) 85vw, 420px" /></p>]]></content:encoded>
        <wfw:commentRss>http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/06/07/2019/estagio-loja-de-autopecas-av-ipanema-3/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
        <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>`;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');

var ces = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/', 'encoded');

console.log(ces.length);
```

Claro que como eu disse no começo o conteúdo dentro de CDATA não é processado, pois justamente este é o objetivo do CDATA ([Para que serve <! [CDATA []]> em XML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81536/3635)), então no caso terá que fazer outro parse, já fizemos o parse para o RSS agora é o parse para o conteudo HTML dentro deste RSS, exemplo:

```js
var data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    >

<channel>
    <title>Parceria Social de Empregos</title>
    <atom:link href="http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br</link>
    <description>Um blog com vagas de emprego</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Sat, 06 Jul 2019 17:05:44 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <language>pt-BR</language>
    <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
    <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=4.9.10</generator>

    <image>
        <url>http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/cropped-logo_01-1-32x32.png</url>
        <title>Parceria Social de Empregos</title>
        <link>http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br</link>
        <width>32</width>
        <height>32</height>
    </image> 
    <item>
        <title>Estágio loja de autopeças Av Ipanema</title>
        <link>http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/06/07/2019/estagio-loja-de-autopecas-av-ipanema-3/</link>
        <comments>http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/06/07/2019/estagio-loja-de-autopecas-av-ipanema-3/#respond</comments>
        <pubDate>Sat, 06 Jul 2019 17:05:44 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[Watanabe]]></dc:creator>
        <category><![CDATA[Vaga de Emprego]]></category>

        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/?p=25590</guid>
        <description><![CDATA[Você gosta do mundo automotivo? Esta pode ser sua chance de conhecer mais sobre a área! Obrigatório: &#8211; Estar cursando o 2º ou 3º ano do Ensino Médio em 2019; &#8211; Residir próximo a Avenida Ipanema; &#8211; Gostar do mundo automotivo; &#8211; Aptidão em português e matemática; &#8211; Disponibilidade aos domingos. Enviar currículo para rh@watanabeautopecas.com.br]]></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p><img class="alignnone wp-image-1941" src="http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/estagio-watanabe-300x75.jpg" alt="" width="420" height="105" srcset="http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/estagio-watanabe-300x75.jpg 300w, http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/estagio-watanabe.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 420px) 85vw, 420px" /></p>]]></content:encoded>
        <wfw:commentRss>http://parceriasocialdeempregos.com.br/06/07/2019/estagio-loja-de-autopecas-av-ipanema-3/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
        <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>`;

var parser = new DOMParser;
var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');

var ces = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/', 'encoded');

//Executa só se a tag existir
if (ces.length) {
    let ce = ces.item(0).textContent;
    let htmlParser = new DOMParser;
    let htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(ce, 'text/html');

    let imgs = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('img');

    console.log(imgs.item(0));
}
```

---

### Resolução

Para adiantar, toda introdução da resposta foi para explicar como funciona as coisas para que no futuro você adapte para outros códigos, mas neste código especifico você pode fazer assim (**leia os comentários**):

```
  //Pode aplicar o ANY direto na variavel
  let items: any = doc.querySelectorAll("channel > item");

  for (let el of items) {
    let obj = {
      "title": el.querySelector("title").textContent,
      "link": el.querySelector("link").textContent,
      "author": el.querySelector("creator").textContent,
      "description": el.querySelector("description").textContent,
      "pubDate": el.querySelector("pubDate").textContent,
      "content": el.querySelector("encoded").textContent,
      "thumbnail": this.getImgFromEncodedTag(el)
    }
    objs.unshift(obj);
  }

  ...

private getImgFromEncodedTag(el)
{
    let ces: any = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/', 'encoded');

    //Executa só se a tag existir
    if (ces.length) {
        let ce = ces.item(0).textContent;
        let htmlParser = new DOMParser;
        let htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(ce, 'text/html');

        let imgs = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('img');

        //Verifica se existem imagens
        if (imgs.length) {
             return imgs[0].src;
        }
    }

    //Se não houver imagens retorna null
    return null;
}
```